# goto definition (gd) while inside function call

Tags: vim

If I am editing a function call like:

```
many_params(param1, "a long...string", p|aram3); // Cursor located at |
```

Then typing `gd` will jump to the definition of `param3`, not `many_params`. What is the most efficient idiom for moving the cursor to `many_params`, without using `^`.

To clarify, please do **not** answer with `^`, because I want an idiom that is also compatible with:

```
// Lets jump to func3's definition
func1(func2(123, "aaaaa"), func3("bbbbb", 3|, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only idea I have is to:

- go to the left opening parenthesis - `F(`
- move one word backwards - `b`

so the command is `F(b`. However it won't work with text like `func1("abc(d", 222|2)`

Comment: Good solution. I think it's possible to come up with a good mapping. I always try to get a mapping when I have this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using `%%b` but the stretch for `%` slows me down. I'm relatively new to Vim, so `F(` wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It feels a bit dirty to me, but you can handle nested parentheses as well with `ya(h`.  Note that this yanks the parenthesized bits to your yank buffer, which may not be desirable, but you would work around that by mapping to `"_ya(h`.  This will go to the open paren of the enclosing parens, and subsequent executions of it will go to subsequent levels of parenthesization.  I don't know of another way to get to the enclosing parentheses without being interrupted by intervening parentheticals.

If you're using this, you need to use the `h` instead of `b` in case you have multiple parentheses in a row.  ...but then again, maybe the behavior with `b` would be desirable.